# Maximum GCD among all subarrays of size >= 2

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Given, an array, write a program to find the maximum gcd among all the subarrays of the size >= 2 of the given array
Example :  2 3 4 4 4
Output: 4 ([4, 4, 4])

My code:

```
from fractions import gcd
from functools import reduce
def GCD(arr):
   x = reduce(gcd, arr)
   return x
t = int(input())
for T in range(0, t):
   n = int(input())
   arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
   gcdd = -1
   for i in range(n):
      for j in range(i+2, n):
         gcdd = max(gcdd, GCD(arr[i:j]))
print(gcdd)
```

It is O(N^2) can it be any more optimized?

Answer (score 1):

I think max(GCD(subarray Size > = 2)) == max(GCD(Subarray Size == 2))

because

suppose there is an array a,b,c,d

then 
GCD(a,b,c) = GCD(GCD(a,b),c)

mean GCD(a,b,c)<=GCD(a,b)

mean there no need to calculate the GCD of size more then 2 if you increase the size of subarray the GCD remain constant or decrease .
There is no Case if you increase size then Gcd increase .

Calculate the GCD of subarray of size 2 is O(2*N) which is almost equal to O(N).

I think you understand what I want to say.